# How to find python source code for an operator preset

Tags: python, modeling, scripting, operator

I'm new to python and Blender and sometimes I find strange things. My problem is I'm trying to understand an operator behavior but something's missing.
I'm in this situation:

[image]

I select a mesh outside edges then I call a grid fill operator. Then the operator runs and I'm presented with the filled mesh and the parameter window where I can change values.

[image]
I'd like to know how that value, precisely "12", is set. From tests I did, it looks like it's something related to the number of selected edges, and changes every time geometry is changed. To correctly use the operator, I need to know how it's set, hence my question: how can I find that operator preset source code?
Mind, I'm not asking about this:

[image]

I already know that. I'm asking where is the source code which sets the "12" value. Thank you.

Comment: At a first glance, I guess the value is calculated on the fly. based on the selection, there is no preset (in this case). You can find the UI code for `MESH_OT_fill_grid` operator in `source/blender/editors/mesh` and the function `bm_grid_fill` in `source/blender/bmesh/operators/bmo_fill_grid.c`. That's exposed to the python api as `...mesh.fill_grid()` with a span default value of  `1` as you can see in the console or here: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=fill_grid#bpy.ops.mesh.fill_grid

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion is correct. I've checked briefly but still no luck. I'll be checking it better next time or I'll debug it...

Comment: Still not sure where your "confusion" comes from. Most (interactive) operators written in C for speed reasons. However, by design we can call all operators, no matter if the operator is written in python or c, the same way `bpy.ops.CATEGORY.NAME`, what's actually pretty nice. Why you are out of "luck"? Blenders API is well designed compared to others IMHO.

Comment: I was referring to that preset value of "12". In the C code (mind, I'm not completely sure) I didn't found where it is calculated... most probably based on selection, that what I want to find, so I could understand how the choice is made for different kinds of objects... just this... for all the rest, your hints are right.. I think you can post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following advice by [brockmann](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/31447/brockmann), here is the code (from editmesh_tools.c in source/blender/editors/mesh)

```
const int clamp = em->bm->totvertsel;
int span;
int offset;

if (RNA_property_is_set(op->ptr, prop_span)) {
    span = RNA_property_int_get(op->ptr, prop_span);
    span = min_ii(span, (clamp / 2) - 1);
    calc_span = false;
}
else {
    span = clamp / 4;
    calc_span = true;
}
```

so it appears span is the number total vertex divided by 4. The value is then modified by another utility which extract two loops from a single one dividing geometry by angle.
Everything is done for you if you call bpy.ops.mesh.fill_grid() from a script.